# How to join in two tables when one table doesn't have a definition for the other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

EDIT: Here is the Entity Data Class

```
public abstract class EntityData : ITableData
{
    protected EntityData();

    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Sales model that looks like this

```
 public class Sale : EntityData
 {
      public string StoreId { get; set; }
      [StringLength(255)]
      public string Remarks { get; set; }
      public string SaleTransactionId { get; set; }

      public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
 }
```

I've used a LINQ statement to get all but I'm also trying to get `PartNumber` from the `Products` table

```
 private MobileServiceContext context;

 var query = context.Sales             
      .Where(s =>
      (String.IsNullOrEmpty(storeName) || s.Store.StoreName.Contains(storeName)) &&
      (String.IsNullOrEmpty(productPartNumber) || s.Product.PartNumber.Contains(productPartNumber)) &&
      (String.IsNullOrEmpty(remarks) || s.Remarks.Contains(remarks)) &&
      (String.IsNullOrEmpty(saletransactionId) || s.SaleTransactionId.Contains(saletransactionId)) );
```

Is there a way to get `PartNumber` from `Products` without declaring `public virtual Product Product { get; set; }`?

EDIT: I've tried `.Inlude()` but to no luck

Comment: Can you show EntityData class?

Comment: I've added the EntityData class

Answer (score 0):

The way you've presented this is a bit confusing.

Each sale has a number of products usually not just one.

I am guessing your SaleTransactionId is the unique identifier for your Sale and it's actually a Guid. If that's the case it should be called SaleId or your object should be called SaleTransaction. That way your intent is clear and you know what each field represents.

This is usually  one of the downsides of using a Code first approach.

Anyway, moving on, you need to be able to link up your Sale to the Product or List of Products so yes you will need that in your Sale object.

What I don't understand is how can your SaleTransactionId be null or empty. Surely it's always populated otherwise there wouldn't be a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just add a .Include

```
 var query = context.Sales   
      .Include(p => p.Product)          
      .Where(s =>
           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(storeName) || s.Store.StoreName.Contains(storeName)) &&
           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(productPartNumber) || s.Product.PartNumber.Contains(productPartNumber)) &&
           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(remarks) || s.Remarks.Contains(remarks)) &&
           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(saletransactionId) || s.SaleTransactionId.Contains(saletransactionId)));
```